# How to add a variable to a selector that is already concatenated?

Tags: jquery, variables, concatenation, selector

i am trying to get the data-lvl from a div and use it in a button's data
i can't figure out how to put the variable **dataquestion** inside the selector
knowing that the selector itself is already concatenated

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'></div>

<div class='question' data-question='5' data-lvl='2'>

</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  dataquestion=5;

  $('#result').html(<button type='button' data-lvl='"+$('.question[data-question="+ dataquestion +"]').data('lvl') +"[option]'>lorem ipsum</button>');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct, the issue is simply that the string concatenation is broken by the mis-matched quotes. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let dataquestion = 5;

  $('#result').html('<button type="button" data-lvl="' + $('.question[data-question="' + dataquestion + '"]').data('lvl') + '[option]">lorem ipsum</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class='question' data-question="5" data-lvl="2"></div>
```

Also note that you could use Template literals to make the string concatenation slightly more succinct, assuming you don't need IE support:

```
$('#result').html(`<button type="button" data-lvl="${$('.question[data-question="' + dataquestion + '"]').data('lvl')}[option]">lorem ipsum</button>`);
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help